# Path Variable not working - 404 resource not available

Tags: java, spring

This is my java controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resetPassword")

@Service
public class GmiResetPasswordController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/resetPassword/{id}/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public
        @ResponseBody
        AnalystDetails getDetails(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") int id, @PathVariable("token") String token) { 
//getDetails
[...]
```

I am trying to get use this URL : http://localhost:8080/resetPassword/59/3e3ac731-3ac4-45eb-8bf6-5f8e4b00298c

this is my spring security xml:

```
<security:http pattern="/resetPassword/**" security="none">
</security:http>
```

any help??

**EDIT**
Changed the Controller to:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resetPassword")
public class GmiResetPasswordController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public
        @ResponseBody
        AnalystDetails getDetails(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable(value = "id") int id, @PathVariable(value = "token") String token) {
[...] 
}
```

Still not working.. this is the link: http://localhost:8080/resetPassword/59/52ed96c3-5041-4ff9-be66-0aa2dbeca713

Comment: Why is your controller annotated with @Service? Remove the service annotation. You are mapping to resetPassword at your controller level and at the method level, so the url you are mapping is /resetPassword/resetPassword/{id}/{token} Remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping should be like this :

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resetPassword")
public class GmiResetPasswordController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public AnalystDetails getDetails(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") int id, @PathVariable("token") String token) { 

        //...

    }

}
```